# Trigger on EmailAfterInsert

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, email

i'm facing an issue with this trigger on EmailMessage after insert.
What i want is simply catch email body from email message and populate a specified field on cases.
The trigger works fine but when i click "run all tests" another test class doesn't pass all its methods reporting an issue about duplicated Id in list.
The error is caused by the "update cas" of my trigger and it's linked to "insert email message" of one test class.
It also reports even if 1 out of 3 method doesn't pass i have code coverage of 100%.
Could you please help me out?
Thank you

Here it is the code:

```
trigger EmailMessageAfterInsert on EmailMessage (after insert) {
List<Case> cas = new List<Case>();
    for (EmailMessage Mess : Trigger.new) {
        if (Mess.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Case.SObjectType) {
            cas.add(new Case(
                    Id = Mess.ParentId,
                    Testo_Email_Azienda__c = Mess.HtmlBody

                    )
              );
        }
    } 
    upsert cas; 
}
```

Comment: can you post your test class which is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update error you're getting looks to be caused by the fact you are adding several cases to the list called `cas` but you're assigning their ID as the Mess.ParentId. This means if your two or more of the new email messages that have been inserted are attached to the same case, the loop will add two cases with the same ID into the list.

If that is the problem, this code should fix it:

```
trigger EmailMessageAfterInsert on EmailMessage (after insert) {

Map<Id, Case> cas = new Map<Id, Case>();

    for (EmailMessage Mess : Trigger.new) {

        if (Mess.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Case.SObjectType) {

            if (!cas.containsKey(Mess.ParentId)) {

                cas.put(Mess.ParentId,
                        new Case(
                        Id = Mess.ParentId,
                        Testo_Email_Azienda__c = Mess.HtmlBody)
                       );
            }
        }
    }

    upsert cas.values(); 
}
```

As for the 100% code coverage, if your trigger runs with a single EmailMessage it will complete successfully, but it's only in the case I described above where the issue arises.

Comment: Can we assign Id for an object, i thought it is auto generated unless it is a custom field.

Comment: As of API version 27.0, [you can set an ID on an object](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring13/Setting+ID++Fields+for+Updates), but you cannot do an insert call, only an update call (I don't know about upsert in all honesty). If you want to upsert a mix of new objects and existing ones, you'll need to do two separate DML operation on two separate lists.